# What format is old DOS database with file extensions .DBX .IDX .PGX?

Tags: export

I must extract data from old `DBX` files.
This database is not Outlook express. I have tried Visual FoxPro 2.6, 9.0, VFP ODBC Driver, VFP OLE DB provider with no success. DBX are the actual data files. I succesfully extracted the data, but can not convert the number fields, nor understand the relations between tables.
File header begins with `WBDB...` field names, types and sizes. I wrote program to decode the files, but had success only with string fields. The numbers are coded in strange form:

```
Curr_PurchaseCost: 33 33 33 33 33 33 11 40 00 00 00 00
Curr_SalePrice: 66 66 66 66 66 66 12 40 00 00 00 00
SalePrice: 66 66 66 66 66 66 12 40.
```

The other problem is that there is some sort of relation between tables. The `ParentKey` in the child table does not correspond to field ID in master table. Maybe `ParentKey` is some index value, but I don't understand the format of index files `IDX`.

Comment: A quick internet search seems to indicate this is Outlook Express - http://file.org/extension/dbx

Comment: Managed to find an article that sounds relevant ([link](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-fish-out-data-from-fpt-cdx-files-foxpro.1695116/)). Go to the second response, from Cindy Winegarden. Indicates that the .DBX file should be tied to a .DBC file. .DBC is a database metadata file; .DBX is its index file, and .DCT is its memo file. Try to find a VFP ODBC driver, and aim it at the .DBC file (if you have it); that should give you some access to the data. It does sound like a .DBX without a .DBC is probably not terribly useful.

Comment: @Piro If you want to edit your question without peer review, [ask to have your accounts merged](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). It's a simple and quick process in most cases.

Comment: The index file for .DBC is .DCX NOT .DBX,